# Local Word Documents

Tags: word

We are using Sharepoint 2010 with Office 2007.

At a past job I know that it used to be possible for someone to:

1. download a Word document from Sharepoint
2. save it locally
3. close it
4. re-open the document and the link the sharepoint version is maintained (and easily refreshable to get any changes since you downloaded it)

I'm finding however that when I perform step 4 above the link has been severed. Is this because I am using Sharepoint 2010 with Office 2007 or is there a setting that I need to enable?

Note: Also I don't have the Server option in my menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may depend on how you do it and what browser you are using.  If you use "Save As", there is no link to the server maintained.  If you are not using IE, your browser probably downloaded a local copy (again with no link to the server).  If you check-out and opt to "work with local copy", then i believe the link is maintained.

Comment: Where do I see the 'work with local copy' option pls?

Comment: [This help page](https://office.microsoft.com/client/15/serverhelp/preview?AssetId=HA102803583&lcid=1033&products=WSSENDUSER&respos=0&CTT=1&queryid=5abc8247%2Da7ff%2D4982%2Da72a%2D2a8956db0c14) talks about it.  I think there may be a setting that enables the "local draft" feature, though, and I can't seem to find it.